# Examples on how to use FIWARE Sinfonier to analyse NGSI data streams

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cosmos

Since few months a Sinfonier/Storm installation is available as part of FIWARE Cosmos. I would suppose that, in the same way there is a way to pass and process NGSI data in the Hadoop backend, there should be one in Sinfonier / Storm. Unfortunately documentation is not helping on that.

Where is it possible to find an example of analysing NGSI data using FIWARE Sinfornier?

Thx!

PS: the documentation suggested to use the tag "fiware-sinfonier" but it's not yet available, and I can't create it.